# How to mock HttpServletRequest with Headers?

Tags: java, servlets, junit, mockito

I am using [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org) with [JUnit](https://junit.org) to test an application. I need to add headers to an [`HttpServletRequest`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) while mocking. This is the first time I am using mock concept to test the application. How can we set headers to the request object while using this mock concept?

### Application code

```
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("/devices")
public class DvrRestService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DvrRestService.class);

    private DvrMiddleService dvrMiddleService;

    @Inject
    public DvrRestService(DvrMiddleService dvrMiddleService) {
        this.dvrMiddleService = dvrMiddleService;
    }

    @GET 
    @Path("/{deviceId}/metadata")
    public Response getDeviceMetadata(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("deviceId") String deviceId,
        @RequiredSession final Session session) {

        try {
            public static String[] REQUEST_HEADERS = { "if-none-match" };
            List<String> requiredHeaders = Lists.newArrayList(REQUEST_HEADERS);
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
            while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) { // here gettting NullPointerException

                String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
                if (requiredHeaders.contains(headerName.toLowerCase())) {
                    String value = request.getHeader(headerName);
                    if (value != null) {
                        headers.put(headerName, value);
                        System.out.println("headerName: " + headerName + ", Value: " + value);
                    }
                }
            }
            DvrResponse response = dvrMiddleService.getDeviceMetadata(deviceId.toUpperCase(), getHeaders(request));
            return processResponse(response.statusCode, response.getResponse(), DeviceMetadataResponse.class,
                response.getHeaders());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return processErrorResponse(e, new DeviceMetadataResponse(), logger);
        }

    }
}
```

### Test

```
public class DvrRestServiceTest {

    static DvrMiddleService dms;
    static HttpServletRequest request;
    static Session session;
    static DvrRestService drs;
    public static final String DeviceId = "000004D42070";
    @BeforeClass
    public static void init(){
        dms = mock(DvrMiddleService.class);
        request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        session = mock(Session.class);
        drs = new DvrRestService(dms);
    }
    @Test
    public void getDeviceMetadataTest(){
        Response rs = drs.getDeviceMetadata(request, DeviceId, session);
        assertEquals(Response.Status.OK, rs.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: Its wonderful documented, just have a look, u just need to write something like Mockito.when(request.getHeaderNames()).thenReturn(...what you want...)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As a starting point and demonstration for the principal you can start with the following snippet.

```
// define the headers you want to be returned
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put(null, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
headers.put("Content-Type", "text/html");

// create an Enumeration over the header keys
Enumeration<String> headerNames = Collections.enumeration(headers.keySet());

// mock HttpServletRequest
HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
// mock the returned value of request.getHeaderNames()
when(request.getHeaderNames()).thenReturn(headerNames);

System.out.println("demonstrate output of request.getHeaderNames()");
while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println("header name: " + headerNames.nextElement());
}
    
// mock the returned value of request.getHeader(String name)
doAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
    @Override
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        return headers.get((String) args[0]);
    }
}).when(request).getHeader("Content-Type");

System.out.println("demonstrate output of request.getHeader(String name)");
String headerName = "Content-Type";
System.out.printf("header name: [%s]   value: [%s]%n", 
        headerName, request.getHeader(headerName));
}
```

### Output

```
demonstrate output of request.getHeaderNames()
header name: null
header name: Content-Type

demonstrate output of request.getHeader(String name)
header name: [Content-Type]   value: [text/html]
```

Comment: @Sathish Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Wasn't it shorter to create the enumeration with a call to java.util.Collections#enumeration ?

Comment: @473183469 Yes. You are right. `Enumeration<String> headerNames = Collections.enumeration(headers.keySet())` would have been shorter and smarter. ;-)

Comment: `mock(HttpServletRequest.class)` did not work for me. May I request you to please share what version of Mockito are you referring to? I am using mockito-core-3.2.4

Comment: @ScottSummers I reconstructed the example and tested it with `mockito-core-3.2.4`. What issue do you have? A complete working example I pushed at [SO answer to question-37314469](https://github.com/SubOptimal/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/question-37314469)

Comment: Whoa man!! Thanks!! I deleted the jar from `.m2` and downloaded it again. That worked.

Comment: When using an answer-based approach to return based off of a map, it would make more sense to be more general to work for any requested, rather than only for one specific header.  That way it'll work for all headers in the map, not just the one.  In other words, `.getHeader(any())` rather than just `.getHeader("Content-Type")`.  If you're only mocking the one, `doReturn` would be more natural than `doAnswer`: `doReturn("text/html").when(request).getHeader("Content-Type");`.

Answer (score 12):

For [`HttpServletRequest`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletrequest), I would recommend using a fully functional mock type instead of directly mocking it with Mockito mocks.  The [`spring-test`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-overview) library has [`MockHttpServletRequest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html) for this purpose:

```java
@BeforeClass
public static void init(){
    // ...

    MockHttpServletRequest mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    mockRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    mockRequest.addHeader("if-none-match", "*");
    mockRequest.addHeader("customHeader", "customValue");

    this.request = mockRequest;
}
```

### Rationale

[`HttpServletRequest`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletrequest) is a complex interface with over 20 methods, with well-defined interplay between them.  Using a fully functional mock type for `HttpServletRequest` from a library simplifies the mocking, removing the need to carefully mock out the methods you're using.

One advantage of this approach is that it is more resilient in the face of future refactorings that get the same information using other methods on the class.  In the case of retrieving the "if-none-match" header in `HttpServletRequest`, I see three different methods that could legitimately be used to retrieve the header: [`getHeader(String name)`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletrequest#getHeader(java.lang.String)), [`getHeaders(String name)`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletrequest#getHeaders(java.lang.String)), and [`getHeaderNames()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletrequest#getHeaderNames()).  Furthermore, the argument for both `getHeader` and `getHeaders` are case-insensitive (the same results are returned for "if-none-match", "If-None-Match", etc.), so any possible argument casing would be correct.  It's very possible to support this with a direct mock, though it involves extra boilerplate code that complicates the test and makes it less obvious.

The [`MockHttpServletRequest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html) class from the [`spring-test`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-overview) library mocks this interface, and allows setting the header and other values via a straightforward API.  While the library is designed for testing [Spring](https://spring.io) applications, the `MockHttpServletRequest` class is independent of any Spring-specific functionality, and should be completely usable on its own even if the application doesn't use Spring.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case

```
mockMvc.perform(post("<<url>>").content("<<jsonStrig>>").header("key", "value"));
```

can also be used in get request.

Answer (score -3):

I know the OP is using Mockito. This answer is for those using spock. You can accomplish this pretty easily.

```
class MyTestSpec extends Specification {

    HttpServletRequest request = Mock()
    MyTestClass myTestClass = new MyTestClass()

    def 'my test'() {
        setup:
        String expectedHeader = "x-mycustom-header"

        when:
        String someResult = myTestClass.someTestMethod()

        then:
        // here is where you return your header from the mocked request
        1 * request.getHeader(_ as String) >> expectedHeader
    }
}
```